# How to create Event Subscription for Event Grid Domain Topic using arm template

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

I want to use the arm template to create the **Event Subscription** for the **Event Grid Domain Topic**. It's ok when I create **Event Grid Domain** and **Event Grid Domain Topic** but when I try to create the **Event Subscription** to listen to messages from **Event Grid Domain Topic**. It always fails. I think I defined the wrong "*scrope*" or "*dependsOn*".
Actually, I can't find the document or tutorial to create the **Event Subscription** for **Event Grid Domain Topic**. Almost document guide the way to create the **Event Subscription** for **Event Grid Topic**.

Thanks for support

This is my arm template

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions",
  "apiVersion": "2021-06-01-preview",
  "name": "[parameters('eventSubscription')]",
  "scope": "[format('Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/topics/{0}', concat(variables('eventGridDomainName'), '/',parameters('topic')))]",
  "properties": {
    "deadletterdestination": {
      "endpointType": "StorageBlob",
      "properties": {
        "blobContainerName": "parameters('containerName')",
        "resourceId": "/subscriptions/{subscriptions}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{containerName}"
      }
    },
    "destination": {
      "endpointType": "WebHook",
      "properties": {
        "endpointUrl": "string"
      }
    },
    "eventDeliverySchema": "EventGridSchema",
    "filter": {
      "advancedFilters": [],
      "enableAdvancedFilteringOnArrays": true
    },
    "labels": []
  },
  "dependsOn": [
   "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventGrid/domains/topics',variables('eventGridDomainName'),parameters('topic')]"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the scope a bit to get it working, take a look at the snippet below.

```
  "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.EventGrid/domains', '/', parameters('domains_azdomaineg_name'), '/', 'topics', '/', parameters('topicName'))]"
```

/

```
{
      "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions",
      "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('domains_azdomaineg_name'), 'topic-dommain-subscription')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventGrid/domains', parameters('domains_azdomaineg_name'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventHubs', parameters('eventHubNamespace'), parameters('eventHubName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "destination": {
          "endpointType": "EventHub",
          "properties": {
            "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhubs', parameters('eventHubNamespace'), parameters('eventHubName'))]"
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "includedEventTypes": [
            "first, last"
          ],
          "advancedFilters": [
            {
              "key": "dataversion",
              "operatorType": "StringIn",
              "values": [
                "test"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.EventGrid/domains', '/', parameters('domains_azdomaineg_name'), '/', 'topics', '/', parameters('topicName'))]"

    }
  ]
}
```